# Embedding an existing web service inside a SharePoint iframe and passing in the Authenticated user

Tags: authentication

Apologies if this doesn't really fit here, but I think I'm in that situation where I'm pretty sure the info is out there, but I just don't know what to search for to find it.

What I'm looking to do is to take an existing set of web applications and embed them inside an iframe in a SharePoint Portal.  They really don't need to be tightly coupled to the portal, I'd just need to:

1. Grab the authenticated userID/sessionID and add that to the URL
2. Have the response appear "inside a frame" in the portal
3. Have any HTML form submissions sent to the existing web app and the new response appear in the same "frame"

It seems like it should be straight forward, but I'm having troubles finding out how to do it.

- I know the existing SharePoint Portal has a userID and a sessionID, that I can access in the back-end database that supports the SharePoint Portal, but how do I access these variables to add them to the web service URL?
- How do I add the SharePoint links that will initiate the frame to call the lead-in URL for the existing web apps?
- Do I need VisualStudio to do the SharePoint edits/updates?

I guess the big issue is that I don't know how to ask the questions I need answers too in so that the search engines will return the info I need.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to pass the UserID as the authentication mechanism used on the web services themselves will handle that automatically and far more securely than a querystring can hope to.  However, if you need to also pass Session variables, then you may need to [create your own custom web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx) that builds the IFrame URL using those variables and writes it out to the browser.

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't need the UserID; however, the SharePoint Portal is used as a front-end to an existing non-MS database that is the engine for the previous non-SharePoint web interface. There's an cross-reference inside the database that controls who has web access and links to their database "userID".  The key to the cross-ref is the same as the SharePoint loginID.  I was hoping to pass the authenticated user into the back end so it can be used as the key to the cross-ref.  I'll have to double check exactly what SharePoint session variables are available.